# The image of an ideal by a ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $\varphi: R \rightarrow S$ be a NOT surjective ring homomorphism. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Then it can be easily proved that $\varphi(I)$ is an ideal of $\varphi(R)$. I know a counterexample when $\varphi(I)$ is not an ideal of $S$ (when $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z}[x]$). But can it happen that $\varphi(I)$ will be an ideal of $S$ for a NOT surjective $\varphi$? Could you show me an example, please?

Comment: $I=\{0\}{}{}{}?$

Comment: Thanks, it is true. But I would want to see some another example.

Comment: If you have an idempotent $e\in R$, $eR$ is an ideal that is also a ring with unit $e$; then the inclusion $eR \to R$ is usually not surjective but its image is an ideal

Comment: @Max This is not a ring homomorphism (unless you don't require preservation of the identity).

Comment: @egreg : indeed, it depends on what the OP means with ring morphism. If you require preservation of identity there should still be some examples, say $B$ is a proper subring of $C$ with inclusion $i$, then $id_A \times i : A\times B\to A\times C$ preserves the identity, is not surjective, and sends $A\times\{0\}$ to $A\times\{0\}$, and they're both ideals